# `poweroff --poweroff` difference with `poweroff`

Tags: shutdown

Is there some difference here between simple

```
poweroff
```

and

```
poweroff --poweroff
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `man poweroff` command to see the manual page for the `poweroff` command:

```
NAME

       halt, poweroff, reboot - Halt, power-off or reboot the machine

SYNOPSIS

       halt [OPTIONS...]

       poweroff [OPTIONS...]

       reboot [OPTIONS...]

DESCRIPTION

       halt, poweroff, reboot may be used to halt, power-off or reboot the machine.
<...snip...>

       -p, --poweroff
           Power-off the machine, regardless of which one of the three commands is invoked.
```

As described in the last sentence, `halt --poweroff`, `poweroff --poweroff` and `reboot --poweroff` perform the same actions.

Comment: man NAMEOFCOMMAND makes this kind of information available to you from any shell prompt. It's useful to know.